# Finding the positions of a particular byte in byte buffer

Tags: java, arrays, bytebuffer

I have a byte buffer from which i need to find the positions of character **'/n'** in that buffer. There may be many **'/n'** present in that byte buffer and i need to find all those positions. Is there any way in which i did not need to convert into byte array and loop over it using Java 8?

Comment: By "byte buffer" do you mean `java.nio.ByteBuffer`? Are you looking for the two characters `/n` (i.e. `/` followed by `n`) or are you looking for the _single character_ `\n` (notice forward-slash vs backslash)? Do you know what encoding is being used?

Comment: Yes, nio bytebuffer. And i need to compare new line character in ASCII which would be '10' instead of `/n/. I tried using streams and got it worked out using the below code. int[] indicesOfNewLineCharacter = IntStream.range(0, initialArray.length)
    .filter(i -> initialArray[i] == findByte)
    .toArray();

Comment: That still seems to be converting your `ByteBuffer` into a `byte[]`. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ByteBuffer` class offers absolute *get* operations which can access the value at any valid index. For instance, [`ByteBuffer#get(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#get(int)) accepts an index and returns the byte at that index. It does this without mutating the position of the buffer, meaning your code won't have any side-effects. Here's an example which finds all indices of a single byte:

```java
public static int[] allIndicesOf(ByteBuffer buf, byte b) {
  return IntStream.range(buf.position(), buf.limit())
      .filter(i -> buf.get(i) == b)
      .toArray();
}
```

This avoids copying the information into a `byte[]` and leaves the `ByteBuffer` in the same state as it was when given to the method. Also note that the buffer is only searched from its current *position* to its *limit*. If you want to search the entire buffer then use `range(0, buf.capacity())`.

Here's another example except this one allows you to search for a "sub-array" in the buffer:

```java
public static int[] allIndicesOf(ByteBuffer buf, byte[] b) {
  if (b.length == 0) {
    return new int[0];
  }
  return IntStream.rangeClosed(buf.position(), buf.limit() - b.length)
      .filter(i -> IntStream.range(0, b.length).allMatch(j -> buf.get(i + j) == b[j]))
      .toArray();
}
```

---

> The code works for getting the position. Is it possible if i just want to delete that ASCII char '10' when found in bytebuffer fro that byte buffer?

Here's an example of removing all occurrences of the specified byte:

```java
public static void removeAll(ByteBuffer buf, byte b) {
  for (int i = buf.position(); i < buf.limit(); i++) {
    // find first occurrence
    if (buf.get(i) == b) {
      // copy every remaining byte which != 'b' over
      for (int j = i + 1; j < buf.limit(); j++) {
        if (buf.get(j) != b) {
          buf.put(i++, buf.get(j));
        }
      }
      // update limit of buffer (implicitly causes outer for loop to exit)
      buf.limit(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. both of them works. Will use the above one since it does not create an array.

Comment: Glad to help. The second example is meant for if and when you want to search for matching regions in the buffer, similar to how [`String#indexOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) works. For instance, maybe you want to look for `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: Hi Slaw, The code works for getting the position. Is it possible if i just want to delete that ASCII char '10' when found in bytebuffer fro that byte buffer?

Comment: Hi Slaw, i was able to get the required result of removing those required bytes from the byte buffer but now the result i get is in int[], is there any way to get the required result in byte[]?

Comment: I added an example at the end of my answer that shows how to remove all occurrences of a byte from a buffer in place (i.e. does not require creating a copy).

Comment: Correct, that i solved it using the code IntStream.range(bb.position(), bb.limit())
       .filter(i -> bb.get(i) != 13)
       .map(i -> bb.get(i)) 
          .toArray();  but this is going to return int[], trying to get byte[] as a result of this.

Comment: If you want to use streams then you'll have to manually copy the `int[]` over into a `byte[]` (i.e. `byteArray[i] = (byte) intArray[i]`). Not sure why you want to do it this way? Your original question seemed intent on avoiding unnecessary copies, so that's what my example does.

Comment: Actually i forgot to mention this point, originally i do have a byte buffer and want to create a byte buffer out of that which will not contain the ASCII '/n', thought of streams because of faster processing but now stuck with converting int[] to byte[].