# Remove some bytes from byte buffer and returning same byte buffer

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer, carriage-return

I have a byte buffer from which i need to remove some bytes of carriage return `/r` and return the same byte buffer after removal. With help i was able to remove the the `/r` using stream as below but that return a `int[]`, is there any way where i do not need to create another byte buffer and use the same one after removing the `/r`? Below is the code i used

```
IntStream.range(bb.position(), bb.limit())
          .filter(i -> bb.get(i) != 13)
          .map(i -> bb.get(i)) 
          .toArray();
```

Let me know any other way to do this?

Comment: What type of buffer do you mean, could you provide the decleration of your buffer, the ´bb´?

Comment: ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(32548);

Comment: "_is there any way where i do not need to create another byte buffer and use the same one after removing the /r?_" – I don't understand. My answer to your previous question tells you exactly how to do this (similar to Lino's answer here), but in the comments you said you want a new buffer instance.

Comment: @Slaw as you've provided the solution in your answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532572/finding-the-positions-of-a-particular-byte-in-byte-buffer), I think we can close this as a dupe?

Comment: @Lino Not sure. My answer may solve this question but the two questions themselves are different (the solution to this question in my answer was more of a "bonus").

Answer (score 1):

You could use this helper method:

```
public static int removeAll(ByteBuffer buf, int b) {
    int removed = 0;
    for (int i = 0, start = 0, cap = buf.capacity(); i < cap; i++) {
        byte read = buf.get(i);
        buf.put(i, (byte) 0);
        if (read != b) {
            buf.put(start++, read);
        } else {
            removed++;
        }
    }
    return removed;
}
```

Which you can then call like this:

```
removeAll(buf, '\r');
```

It simply iterates the buffer, and removes the bytes that are equal to the provided argument, leaving `0` at the end of the buffer to account for the missing elements.

Comment: `removeAll(ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 13, 4, 5, 13}, 13)` -> `{0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 13}` 　　Do you need `buf.put(i, (byte) 0);`?

Comment: @saka1029 good catch, fixed it, by always putting a `0` at index `i` into the buffer, and yes it is needed, else we would have trailing bytes at the end which we have moved earlier to another position